# Логика аплоада изображений

Tags: изображения, загрузка

Допустим у нас есть сайт, на котором пользователи могу предлагать новости.

Что если

**1.** Пользователь прикрепил (загрузил изображения ajax методом на сервер) и закрыл форму ?

- Получается изображения будут ничейными, т.е не прикрепленные к какому либо посту

**2.** Как избежать перегрузки, к примеру пользователь может заходить каждый раз на форму, и загружать фотографии, потом уходить с нее, и повторять тоже самое. Т.е получается можно бесконечно загружать изображения на сервер.

- Что делать в этом случае ?

Я думаю ситуацию вы поняли, я просто хочу понять логику такой работы, и как правильно ее организовать. Какие методы есть защиты, фильтрации ? Единственное что пришло в голову, это создание буферной зоны с лимитированием находящихся в ней файлов... но не думаю что это оптимальный вариант, так как если кто то переполнить это зону до лимита.

Хотел бы услышать совет как правильно а главное если можно просто это организовать.

Comment: Вопрос, по поводу, отправки самой формы, допустим мы закачали 3 файла на сервер, в форме имена файлов мы положили в скрытые инпуты, потом отправляем форму, пхп считывает имена со скрытых инпутов, и начинает работу с файлами. Вопрос безопасно ли отображать имена файлов в скрытых инпутах при отправки формы ?

Answer (score 1):

Не слышал ни о каких хитрых решениях этой проблемы и в своем опыте не встречал. Все варианты достаточно очевидны:

- ограничение суммарного объема передаваемых данных на пользователя за промежуток времени. Его можно сделать достаточно большим. К примеру - 1гб в час, на мой взгляд, за глаза в вашем случае.
- ограничение количества передаваемых файлов на пользователя за единицу времени.
- установка ttl (времени жизни) для "свободных" файлов и удаление их после истечения времени. Тут исходите из вероятного времени заполнения вашей формы со всеми возможными задержками. Хотя, я бы ставил ttl не меньше суток в любом случае.
- последний вариант очень кастомный и требуется, на мой взгляд, только если у вас действительно остро стоит такая проблема. Исходя из логики работы вашего приложения пишем код, который отслеживает количество и скорость появления "свободных" файлов на пользователя (с учетом того, заполняет ли он до конца форму или нет) и, когда величина достигает определенного значения, начинаем выдавать ошибку загрузки. Блокируем на час, к примеру. Это, опять же, зависит от того, насколько низкое ограничение мы поставили. Если разрешено залить 5 файлов за 10 минут не более 100МБ - блочим на 10 минут. Если 20 файлов за час на 200МБ - блочим на час.

Самое важное и первостепенное - понять, насколько остро стоит проблема. По моему опыту, излишняя "предусмотрительность" только отнимает время и усложняет проект. Если у вас еще даже нет намека на эту проблему - лучше не делать никаких фильтров. Сделать обязательно очистку файлов раз в сутки и добавить логирование по интересующим критериям - количество файлов, объем файлов или что-то подобное. Плюс - для проекта серьезного проекта обязательно подключить систему мониторинга с метриками и уведомлениями (типа zabbix) и настроить там мониторинг интересующих параметров с уведомлениями при критическом увеличении. Таким образом, если вдруг кол-во файлов резко попрет вверх - вы это не пропустите, примете меры и задумаетесь, как фильтровать их в дальнейшем.

Я делал похожую схему в нескольких последних проектах. Проекты были закрытые, поэтому там вопроса злоумышленников не стояло. Но и у вас пока не стоит и меры нужны исключительно профилактические. Итак. 
Все загруженные файлы добавляются в базу. При сохранении формы у этих записей в базе появляются связи с сущностями форм (ну или чего-то другого). Раз в день, скрипт по крону идет по файловой системе и проверяет для каждого файла, есть ли у него соответствующая запись в бд и есть ли у этой записи в бд полезные связи. Если связей нет - файл является мусором и удаляется. 
Следует заметить, что обход файловой системы сопряжен с большой нагрузкой на диск, к тому же , генерируется много запросов в БД. Поэтому все это происходит глубокой ночью и обход происходит частями. Т.е. есть заданное кол-во дней на полный обход, к примеру 10, и каждый день происходит проверка только 1/10 всех файлов. По окончании проверки сохраняется текущий стейт и в следующий раз продолжается с того же места.

P.S. *высказав свое мнение, тем не менее, присоединяюсь к автору и буду очень рад, если кто-то расскажет о элегантных способах решения вопроса.*

Comment: Забыл сказать, что проэкт будет размещен на шаред хостинге. Но с возможнлстью создавать поддомены. В плане безопасности думаю создать поддомен img.site.com  и заливать туда, ну и настроить .htaccess. Но проблема в том что ваши методы хороши только когда у вас полный контроль над сервером, там естесвенно вариантов больше. Но мне нужен вариант именно для шареда, и более оптимальный. Я все склоняюсь к буферной зоне, которая будет контролировать общее кол-во файлов.

Comment: Т.е из буферной зоны, при успешной отправки формы, файлы будут перемещятся в общую папку с изображениями. Т.е они будут считаться валидными так как форма прошла проверку, а значит данные занесены в базу, и картинки перемещаются в орижинал папку. Но если кто то начнет забивать буферную зону аплоадом картинок, и привысит лимит, тогда юзеры не смогут прикреплять изображения. Тут думаю придумать что то интеренсное, как то отловить того кто загружает массого фотографии. Просто не хочется в случае возникновения такой проблемы думать как ее решить, а не множко за ранее подготовится.

Comment: Ух. Шаред хостинг это жестко. Общее кол-во файлов... Может быть я не до конца понимаю вашу идею, но звучит не очень. Т.е. я, (правильный юзер), заполняю форму, приходит он (злоумышленник), начинает спамить файлы, буферная зона забивается, и мои файлы тоже (причем первыми, как более старые) удалятся? На мой взгляд, без контроля по конкретным юзерам не обойтись, при правильной реализации.

Comment: Нет, удалятся ничего не будет, просто нельзя будет закачать изображения, буферная зона так же может служить от наплыва аплоада как бы, к примеру если 20 юзеров будут загружать по 2 картинки одновременно то это 40 файлов (ну это пример) а мы в буферной зоне ставим лимит на хранения 41 файл, то 21-вый юзер если захочет прикрепить картину, ему вылетит сообщение извените проблемы с сервисом и т д... повторите попытку пожже, буферная зона освобождается сама по себе, если там работаю правильные юзеры, т.е отправляют нормально форму. П.с ошибку вылетит не на странице сайта, а над кнопочкой Browse .

Comment: 1 - как очищаться будет буфер? Не очищать нельзя, т.к. неприкрепленный файл это нормально, в небольших количествах они будут неизбежно. На шаред-хостинге крон есть вообще, я не в курсе? 2 - вас не беспокоит, что в случае действий злоумышленника пострадают все остальные пользователи, которым будет заблокирована возможность загрузки? В целом идея заслуживает права на жизнь, тем более в ваших ограниченных условиях. Но додумать детали определенно нужно.

Comment: 1.Да действительно будет проблема с остальными пользователями, в случае если злоумышленник начнет аплоадить массого картинки. То другие не смогут это сделать, пока буфер будет забит ниченыйми файлами (т.е мусором). Тут нужно что то придумать как правильно организовать очистку, или блокировку злоумышленника. Можно было бы создать таблицу, типа лога, в которую бы при аплоаде заносились имена файлов. ну или при сохранении файлов, а потом бы с этой таблицы мы брали имена файлов и проверяли в таблице (с новостью) есть ли в них эти имена, и если нету, то удаляли файл из папки.

Comment: Но если приметь доп тоблицу в качество логирование.. тогда вопрос возникает в запуске чека, даже если есть крон ! злоумышленник может флудить бесконечно, ну или определенный пириод, и просто не давать юзерам загружать что либо. Нужно как то это все продумать. вот и обратился за помощью